# Bluetooth headset with microphone not recognising as an input device

Tags: release-hera, sound, bluetooth, audio

I have a Bluetooth earphone with microphone. I have successfully connected it to my elementary OS. But it shows it only as an output device under the sound setting. It doesn't list under the input devices.
I installed the pavucontrol and tried to see the input devices. It is coming under the Monitor. Where I am listening to something on youtube or something, I can see the movement of the level bar.
I installed the Bluetooth manager from the app store. The audio profile coming by default for my headset is A2DP sink and if I am trying to change it to HSP/HFP. It shows me 'Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit' error.
Can you please help me setting up my audio/Bluetooth drives correctly so that I can use it as a mic also.

[image]